# Rails load different javascript files in different pages using manifest file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using different javascript libraries in different part of my rails app. Currently all my library files are in `application.js` manifest file. And it gets loaded in pages, where it's not required. Is there any way I can load files that are needed in a particular part of my app?

Comment: You probably want to create a separate layout file.

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: I read require js can be used. Will it solve my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a separate "manifest" and load that on demand where you need it. You will have to:

1- Tell Rails to preprocess those files, ie if your file is named `additional_dependencies.js`, then add it in `assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( additional_dependencies.js )
```

2- Load that file where you need it (NOT in the main layout):

```
= javascript_include_tag 'additional_dependencies'
```

And, of course, do not add the files you want to keep as separate dependencies into the `application.js` file (watch for require_tree).